# JavaScript onscroll function doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, html, onload

all I wanna do is fire a function when the page has loaded.

Seems that there is an error in my code but I can't figure it out...Guess I'm still to noobish...

```
<div class="text-one">
   <p id="hi" onscroll="myFunction()"> Hi, </p>
</div>

function myFunction () {
    document.getElementById("hi").style.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Your `<p>` tag isn't scrolling, your `<body>` or `<div>` maybe is

Comment: Execute a JavaScript when a <div> element is being scrolled: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onscroll.asp

Comment: If it is on load of the page, use simple
window.onload = function() { whatever function you want to call }

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="text-one">
   <p id="hi" onscroll="myFunction()"> Hi, </p>
</div>
```

This code means that "when `p` scrolls, do myFunction()". That doesn't make a lot of sense unless you have so much text in your `p` tag that the user is expected to scroll inside the div.

instead:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   myFunction()
});
```

Now we got a listener that listens for when the user scrolls in the window

Not every function should be called from inside a html tag. especially when the context doesn't match up

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this, you must have scrollable element first:
http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/bZOXbG

JS:

```
function myFunction () {
    document.getElementById("hi").style.color = "blue";
}
```

CSS:

```
#hi{
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure your element is scroll-able, by using CSS as below.

```
p#hi
{
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;/*need to specify element height*/
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

need contents to make height more than you defined in CSS.
After these, your code is okay :)

refer [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onscroll.asp) as John commented in your question.